# postmessage without iframes incase of Oauth popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The popup(child) and the parent has diffent origins(for this scenario it is 127.0.0.1-child and localhost-parent).Now I want to pass data from the child to the parent.What I tried

-Creating a variable on the window object and let child set data on that variable.-FAILED because browser wont allow this as the parent url and the child url doesnt match.
-localStorage(kinda hack but just to work this scenario)-.localStorage.setItem("data") sets the data but when retrieving the data by localStorage.getItem("data") unable to get the data.
-Postmessage-This didnt throw any error but the event is not listened.
    Parent

```
                window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);

                function receiveMessage(evt)
                {debugger;
                  if (evt.origin === 'http://my.iframe.org')
                  {
                    alert("got message: "+evt.data);
                  }
                }
```

Child
             `window.postMessage("Hello",<parent url>);`

What is that I am missing?Or there are no ways to achieve this as the parent and the child url doesnt match?

Comment: Try `window.parent.postMessage`.

Comment: @KagamiSaschaRosylight tried but somehow the listner isnt hitting.I am not getting any events fired for the postMessage,very strange.Post message works without iframes,eh?

Comment: What i figured out(for the scenario of sending data from child to parent window) is that the postmessage to work the iframe has to be a part of the parent dom.Only then the event is listened